# Custom logic in Cakephp 3.0 view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is for CakePHP 3.0

I want to encapsulate some nontrivial php logic to be called (reused) several times within one .ctp file for one controller action. I'm trying to figure out the most elegant way of doing it.

I have a few thoughts, none of which seem very elegant:

1. $this in the CTP file execution context is class View. Put methods on the View class to call as $this->function() within the .ctp file. This seems like the wrong division of labor, especially since helpers seem designed for this. Plus the functions would be exposed to all ctp files.
2. Create a helper. This seems like the "best" way to go, but that helper is always loaded and exposed to all .ctp files, which seems like it violates containment since the logic is only relevant to one action's view. In the absence of a better solution, this is the route I'm taking.
3. Create a subclass of View for this element/model and put the logic there, to be accessed as in (1). This seems like the most elegant solution, but it appears that subclassing View is intended for alternate media (eg PDF), and I can't see how to direct Cake to use that class when manufacturing the view for a given controller's action.
4. Shove the function inline in the .ctp file. I'm not even sure if this will work correctly, and it seems ugly to put functions in a .ctp file.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not explaining what kind of super complex logic you want to use there so I would say go for 3). It is very well possible, [you can load helpers in a view files](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.View.View.html#_loadHelper):

```
$this->loadHelper('MyFancyLogic');
```

You can also checkout [view cells](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html). But again, you're not explaining what problem exactly you try to solve it's hard to recommend anything specific. So I would say it's a helper or a view cell.